# Running OpenFace tool on multiple video files via command line

Tags: windows, powershell, terminal, command-line-interface, feature-extraction

I have downloaded the [OpenFace tool](https://github.com/TadasBaltrusaitis/OpenFace) for facial landmark extraction. Following the [wiki](https://github.com/TadasBaltrusaitis/OpenFace/wiki/Command-line-arguments), I am able to extract features of a single video file by running the following on a windows command line interface
`./FeatureExtraction.exe -f "...\CREMA-D\VideoFlash\1001_DFA_ANG_XX.flv" -out_dir ".../openface-output"` where -f represents the path of my input file.

However, I would like to extract ALL the .flv videos in the `...\CREMA-D\VideoFlash` directory at once. Is there an easy way to do this?

**Edit:**
It is possible to add multiple -f flags e.g. `./FeatureExtraction.exe -f "...\CREMA-D\VideoFlash\1001_DFA_ANG_XX.flv" -f "...\CREMA-D\VideoFlash\1002_DFA_ANG_XX.flv" -f "...\CREMA-D\VideoFlash\1003_DFA_ANG_XX.flv" -out_dir ".../openface-output"`. Is there a way to perhaps loop through all the possible files and add this flag using a FOR DO loop?

Or potentially do a for loop of `./FeatureExtraction.exe -f "...\CREMA-D\VideoFlash\[file].flv" -out_dir ".../openface-output"` for each file in a particular directory

Answer (score 2):

My current hackish solution is to start a for loop and iterate through each file in the input location `FOR %i IN ("...\CREMA-D\VideoFlash\*") DO .\FeatureExtraction.exe -f %i -out_dir "...\crema-d\openface-output"`

Comment: This has been working for me, until today. I now get "Failed to open the video file at location: C:..." when I use it. I assumed there way something wrong with the video, but they all open and I can run feature extraction on them individually. Have you encountered this?